# jQuery How To Modify html of a cloned element in memory

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone

I'm trying to modify the html of a template in memory and then prepend it to another html element

```
var messageTemplate = $("#messageTemplate").clone()
                          .removeAttr('id').removeClass("hidden").html();
var timeStamp = message.TimeStamp;
console.log(timeStamp)
var relativeTime = moment(timeStamp, "YYYYMMDD").fromNow();

$(messageTemplate).find("#message").html(message.Data)
$(messageTemplate).find("#moment").html(relativeTime);
$(messageTemplate).find("#senderName").html(message.SenderUser.Username);

$("#message-dropdown").prepend(messageTemplate);
```

Grabing the template works fine and prepending it however,  the html is the original template, and is unmodified even though I'm setting the html.  Can anyone explain how to properly set the html of a cloned element?

I've created a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/d9s6twp1/5/

Comment: `messageTemplate` appears to return `.html()` of  `#messageTemplate` element, that is child elements `.outerHTML`, not `#messageTemplate` element. Can you include `html` at Question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit, Updated

jQuery was not loaded at jsfiddle. Note also that you were previously prepending duplicate `id`s to `document`; `id` in `document` should be unique. Redefine variable `template` when setting unique `id`, new `html` at element. The same process can be used if multiple elements are initially contained within `template` `html` string variable; that is use `.filter()`, create unique `id` for element, define or redefine each variable name which references a cloned element

```js
var template = $("#template")
              .clone().removeAttr("id")
              .removeClass("hidden")
              .html();

console.log(template);

// re-define `template`
template = $(template).filter("#username")
           .attr("id", "username-" + $("[id^=username]").length)
           .html("new user");

console.log(template[0].outerHTML);

$("#container").prepend(template)
```

```css
.hidden{
  display:none;
}

#container{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="template" class="hidden">
<span id="username">Test User</span>
</div>

<div id="container">
<br>
<span>Element container</span>
</div>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/d9s6twp1/7/

---

`messageTemplate` appears to return `.html()` of `#messageTemplate` element, that is child element `.outerHTML`, not `#messageTemplate` element.

Try substituting `.filter()` for `.find()` to filter child element siblings of `#messageTemplate` contained in `messageTemplate` jQuery object.

Comment: @johnny5 _"I tried that I got the same results"_ Can you reproduce issue at stacksnippets, jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net?, include `html` at Question?

Comment: ah so the issue was that I wasn't reassigning it to the template after filter

Comment: @johnny5 Yes, and duplicate `id`s in `document`

Comment: the ids shouldn't cause an issue appending, only when retrieving them again right?

Comment: @johnny5 No, `id` in `document` should be unique, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Comment: I still cannot get this working can you please look at my new fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/d9s6twp1/10/

Comment: @johnny5 You have not included jQuery at jsfiddle?

Comment: ive updated the fiddle with jQuery, I removed the ids all together because they were unneeded after appending.  I'm confused I'm using the filter like above.  Here is the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/d9s6twp1/11/

Comment: In this instance, you can use `.find()` https://jsfiddle.net/d9s6twp1/12/

Comment: using find removes the rest of the template html so it only works for the first, sorry for troubling you so much jsfiddle.net/d9s6twp1/15

Comment: You are re-defining `messageTemplate` at each new line where you set the variable. You could alternatively use destructuring https://jsfiddle.net/d9s6twp1/16/ or an array https://jsfiddle.net/d9s6twp1/17/ to assign each  `html` string or jQuery object in array to a variable

Comment: destructuring example doesn't work, and the array example will unnest the html.  Hmm, I didn't want to have to use a binding frame work, but it looking more and more like I should be

Comment: @johnny5 Did not remove `temp` reference, here, at `console.log(temp)` at destructuring example https://jsfiddle.net/d9s6twp1/18/ _"and the array example will unnest the html."_ What do you mean by "unnest"?

Comment: by doing either one of those, you are modifying the structure of the html, previously the whole container was wrapped in an anchor tag and a few other elements, but now they are just the individual elements with those ids removed from the template structure

Comment: You do not select the anchor tag, you have selected individual elements

Comment: The clone that I grab out I want to act as a template, and only modify the values for those existing elements. I want to leave the template structure intact

Comment: Note, `<span>` is not a valid child element of a `<ul>` element, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul

Comment: @johnny5 Also `blue` `background-color` would not display default blue color of  `a` element; see https://jsfiddle.net/d9s6twp1/19/

Comment: It works yes!  You are the man, if you are ever in NYC comment on here, I owe a beer!

Answer (score 1):

Use class not Id's in the child elements.

```
var messageTemplate = $("#messageTemplate").clone()
                          .removeAttr('id').removeClass("hidden").html();
var timeStamp = message.TimeStamp;
console.log(timeStamp)
var relativeTime = moment(timeStamp, "YYYYMMDD").fromNow();

$(messageTemplate).find(".message").html(message.Data)
$(messageTemplate).find(".moment").html(relativeTime);
$(messageTemplate).find(".senderName").html(message.SenderUser.Username);

$("#message-dropdown").prepend(messageTemplate);
```

Comment: just wonder how that will change anything, I'm calling find on the messageTemplate which is a closed section of the html. So when searching it it should find the proper element